# SQL Server: max of date

Tags: sql-server

**Table 1**

```
RefId       Name
-----       ----
1             A    
2             B
```

**Table 2**

```
RefId             Date
-----             -----
1                 29/03/2018 07:15
1                 29/03/2018 07:30
2                 29/03/2018 07:35
2                 29/03/2018 07:40
```

I would like the result to be as follows (`Refid`  `name` and the `max(date)` from table 1 and 2 for that `refid`)

```
1           A     29/03/2018 07:30
2           B     29/03/2018 07:40
```

Query used

```
select 
    table1.refId, table1.name,
    (select max(date) from table2) 
from 
    table1, table2 
where 
    table1.refid = table2.refid 
group by 
    table2.refid
```

I am getting the following error message

> Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: i did try it out but Table 1 doesn't seem to change the format but for the rest it has changed

Comment: I don't see any SQL in your post that shows that effort, which means it doesn't exist.

Comment: refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: It might be a new ANSI092 SQL standard but there isnt any performance issue and i find it more readable than the ANSI join  and more than 25 years ago, i dont think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`JOIN`** and the aggregate function **`MAX`** with **`GROUP BY`** to select the max date for each `RefId`.

**Query**

```
select [t1].[RefId], [t1].[Name], max([t2].[date] as [date]
from [Table1] [t1]
join [Table2] [t2]
on [t1].[RefId] = [t2].[RefId]
group by [t1].[RefId], [t1].[Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

'29/03/2018 07:15' is nvarchar-type, you need datetime.

nvarchar convert to datetime: `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '29/03/2018 07:15', 103)`

Answer to your example:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(RefId int, Name nvarchar(10));
INSERT INTO @Table1(RefId, Name) VALUES(1, 'A'), (2, 'B');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(RefId int, [Date] nvarchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Table2(RefId, [Date]) 
VALUES
(1, '29/03/2018 07:15'),
(1, '29/03/2018 07:30'),
(2, '29/03/2018 07:35'), 
(2, '29/03/2018 07:40');



SELECT t1.RefId, t1.Name, t2.Date
FROM @Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT RefId,  MAX(CONVERT(datetime, [Date], 103)) AS [Date] 
FROM @Table2
GROUP BY RefId) AS t2
ON t1.RefId = t2.RefId
```